# How asp.net build object from HTML in server

Tags: c#, asp.net, server

I build a page in asp.net which has several buttons. 
The buttons are created dynamicly in the page load event. 
On first load of page (isPostBack=False) i give each button a text and add the buttons to the form.
On PostBack (after button was clicked) i only add buttons to form . 
Also the server has array of all buttons.
The question is - how on PostBack the server knows and gives each button created the corrected Text Value (which was given only on first page load, but on PostBack, before creating the buttons, the button array is null)?

This is a code snippet-

```
protected Button[,] buttons;
    Table table;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        buttons = new Button[4, 4];
        table = new Table();
        Form.Controls.Add(table);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            TableRow row = new TableRow();
            table.Controls.Add(row);
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                row.Cells.Add(cell);

                    buttons[i, j] = new Button();
                    //buttons[i, j].Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
                    buttons[i, j].Click += new EventHandler(b_Click);
                    cell.Controls.Add(buttons[i, j]);


            }
            //table.Controls.Add(row);
        }
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                createButtons(i);
            }
        }

    }

private void createButtons(int i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4 && i*j!=9; j++)
        {
            if (i * j == 9)
            {
                buttons[i, j].Width = 0;
                buttons[i, j].Height = 0;
            }
            Button b = buttons[i, j];
            buttons[i, j] = b;
            b.Height = 100;
            b.Width = 100;
            b.Font.Bold = true;
            b.Font.Size = FontUnit.XLarge;
            b.Text = randomNumber().ToString();
            b.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(r.Next(0, 255), r.Next(0, 255), r.Next(0, 255));

        }
    }
```

Comment: Probably ViewState. Too lazy to check myself but you may try disabling ViewState and see if it still works.

Comment: Yes, You are correct. If ViewState=False than the buttons don't receive the Text Values. But the question is still how the server knows the values for the Buttons ? Does it parse the HTML for this?

Comment: Server knows value, because, those are posted back to server, if you open network console , say in chrome, check request payload , you can see that whole controls are posted back - http://s1223.photobucket.com/user/frostfang83/media/Untitled.png.html

Answer (score 0):

This behavior was one of the key design goals of asp.net.  Microsoft wanted the paradigms of asp.net to be very similar to desktop programing so it would be easier for people to make the transition to using web technologies.  A key part of that was abstracting the sessionless nature of the web which is why asp.net preserves control initialization between requests.

Asp.net does this in a few ways.  The most common is `ViewState` which is a base64 encoding of the entire page control tree stored in a hidden input control and sent to the client on every request.  If you examine the HTML that is sent to the browser you can see this field.

The other mechanism is called `SessionState` which is stored server side.

Scott Mitchell has a very nice article about the inner workings of View State that you can read here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx

Comment: Entire tree is certainly not correct. More like "non-default values" (technically not correct either)

Comment: @Stilgar - Yes there are some nuances to this.  The technical answer is ViewState stores the property values of the controls that have been programatically modified.  However, if you modify a child control programatically, asp.net still builds a tree so it can correctly locate the modified control.